# Export a .sqlite file in C/C++ (on windows)

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

It is possible to move a .sqlite file somewhere while not corrupting it in C or C++?
Somewhere could be another folder or something.

If so could you give me some tips/pointers.

Comment: What's the problem in simply moving the file as you would any other file?

Comment: So I could just use CopyFile() ?

Comment: Why not? It's just a file, it can be copied as a file. Why would it get corrupted?

Comment: I am not sure, I was just assuming. Thank you though!

Comment: do you mean moving the file while it is being accessed? Or just moved in general?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. It is a regular file that can be moved around just like any other file.

The sqlite engine itself will make sure that it does not corrupt. Either it is in a clean state, or locked when being written to (with journaling).

One thing to remember that you should not *use* the database file on filesystems that do not have reliable locking, e.g. on network disks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends a little. It is just a regular file that (assuming nothing is connected to it, writing to it at the time) can be copied without problem. Welcome to the world of open source systems where things really are that simple (ie you don't need to update the registry, a config file or two, reapply installer settings or anything like that).

However, things are tricky if something is using the file. When an app opens a sqlite file it can tell the OS to lock it - the default is open with [exclusive access](https://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3vfsxopen) for the opening app (using a certain flag). In such a case, you will not be able to move the file as the OS will prevent it until the app that has it locked is stopped.